# An homomorphisms from $G$ to $G'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ and $G'$ be two finite groups such that $(\mathcal O(G),\mathcal O(G')) =1$. Then find all the homomorphisms from $G$ and $G'$. $\mathcal O(G)$ means order of group $G$. I tried this problem the whole day couldn't think of a way to solve. Really stuck.

Please help me out.

Comment: Hint: if $h: G\mapsto G'$ is a group homomorphism, then what do you know about the size of the image of $h$, in terms of $O(G)$? What do you know about the sizes of subgroups of $G'$, in terms of $O(G')$? (Incidentally, the order of a group is often written just as $|G|$)

Comment: The order of the image of a homomorphism divides both the order of the domain and the order of the codomain. But such latter orders are relatively prime, by assumption, so...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If you denote $f:G\longrightarrow G'$ such a homomorphism, $f(G)$ is a subgroup of $G'$, hence its  order divides that of $G'$. It is also isomorphic to a quotient of $G$ by the *First isomorphism theorem* and therefore its order divides that of $G$. Can you end the reasoning?

Comment: Still can't get. Can you explain further?

Comment: I've added some more details. Is it clearer now?